# How to get only one row from set which is in condition in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have simple table in Postgres, which stores personal messages of users:

```
 id  | author_id | reciever_id | content  | status_id |       created_at
-----+-----------+-------------+----------+-----------+------------------------
   1 |         1 |          74 | 1 to me  |         1 | 2015-07-31 13:51:49+03
 159 |        81 |          74 | 81 to me |         0 | 2015-07-31 13:51:49+03
 160 |        74 |          81 | I to 81  |         0 | 2015-07-31 13:51:49+03
 161 |        81 |          74 | 81 to me |         0 | 2015-07-31 13:51:49+03
```

I'd like to get "conversations" from this table. This term means that I must to have only one row from such rows which are satisfy condition "get messages where author is mine". These rows will be rendered in view as conversation's header.

I have query (get all messages for me):

```
select * from messages 
<joing table with user's name>
where reciever_id = 74
```

But it gives me

```
  id  | author_id | reciever_id | content  | status_id |       created_at
-----+-----------+-------------+----------+-----------+------------------------
   1 |         1 |          74 | 1 to me  |         1 | 2015-07-31 13:51:49+03
 159 |        81 |          74 | 81 to me |         0 | 2015-07-31 13:51:49+03
 161 |        81 |          74 | 81 to me |         0 | 2015-07-31 13:51:49+03
```

where third row is extra. How to get only one row in query which satisfy condtion ?

Comment: Use top for first row

Comment: Rows 159 and 161 seem to be duplicates (all data except the ID is the same). Can there also be two messages from the same person for you with different data? What then? Would you want to show both or only one of them? If only one of them, which?

Comment: It's duplicated due to I want to show that author can write me several messages regardless they are different or no.,

Comment: Which of the three rows do you want? And why?

Comment: What's "conversations" in this context. Question is unfinished.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join both the tables using the common column. It should be

```
select * from messages as t1 inner join users as t2 
on t1.author_id=t2.user_id
where t1.reciever_id = 74
```

Comment: It's not even close to what OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "limit 1", at the end of you request to get only the first result.

You might want to use order by to specify which is the first row.